# jquery append before final element

Tags: jquery

I have html structured like so.

```
<div id='container'>
  <div class='item'> ... </div>
  <div class='item'> ... </div>
  <div class='item'> ... </div>
  ...
  <div id='item_final'><input type="button" id='addOne'>...</div>
</div>
```

and what I am trying to do it add another item to the container class before the item_final div. The items are dynamic, so the number of them is unkown.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

```
$('#container div:last').before( $('<div>') );
```

Comment: I personally like your approach, if you always want to refer to the "last" instead of a component that's "supposed" to be the last, then this way of doing it is more secure.

Answer (score 29):

Try the [.insertBefore](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/) method.

```
$('<div>').insertBefore('#item_final');
```